Is it just me, or did the tags suddenly get bolded?
When I logged on to this site today, I noticed that the tags looked bold, like this:

Have they always been like this, is this a issue with the new update I just downloaded to my Chromebook, or did the site change the font for tags?

I'm noticing the same thing.

This is intentional, however, it has been reported as a bug at Meta SE and is related to recent tag updates.
Yes this whole answer is bold and it looks terrible. Just like the tags.
